# How to embed "input(id)" into URL in GET request using Python?

Tags: python, http, input, get

A'm just a beginner in Python. Please, help me with such problem:

I have API documentation (Server allowed methods):
GET, http://view.example.com/candidates/, shows a
candidate with id=. Returns 200

I write such code:

```
import requests

url = 'http://view.example.com/candidates/4'
r = requests.get(url)
print r
```

But I want to now how can I put id of candidate through "input()" builtin-function instead of including it to URL.

There is my efforts to do this:

```
import requests
cand_id = input('Please, type id of askable candidate: ')
url = ('http://view.example.com/candidates' + 'cand_id')
r = requests.get(url)
print r
dir(r)
r.content
```

But it's not working...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this to construct the url:

```
url = 'http://view.example.com/candidates'
params = { 'cand_id': 4 }
requests.get(url, params=params)
```

Result: http://view.example.com/candidates?cand_id=4

--

Or if you want to build the same url as you mentioned in your post:

```
url = 'http://view.example.com/candidates'
cand_id = input("Enter a candidate id: ")
new_url = "{}/{}".format(url, cand_id)
```

Result: http://view.example.com/candidates/4

Answer (score 3):

you're using the string `'cand_id'` instead of the variable `cand_id`. The string creates a url of `'http://view.example.com/candidatescand_id'`